# How can I change template of confirmation email in FOSUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I need to change template of confirmation email in FOSUserBundle. I have this settings, but it doesn't work:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true
        email:
            template: AcmeUserBundle:User:confirm.email.twig
```

Error is:

```
Unrecognized options "email" under "fos_user.registration"
```

Comment: It should be noted that, as of 2013-06-11, this is not explained in their docs (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md), and the code above is what I tried, too, extrapolating from their sample on how to alter the template for password reset emails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean confirmation email template?

```
    confirmation:
        enabled:    true
        template:   MgpAppBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Did you read source, or did you find docs on that? Or did you just try-and-error it out?

Comment: @HannoFietz don't remember, but usually I look at the source of [configuration](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/ab580c138577b0d4abae04547a17a01c85cd09f9/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L159).

Comment: Seems like the docs are wrong? Their example is as the OP suggested. Very frustrating.

Comment: @MartinLyne You can check the [configuration builder](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L122). Only `resetting` has `email` options.

Comment: @meze interesting thanks. Still, seems to me that the docs should show an example of both methods if there are 2. Instead of/As well as showing the only example that's different to all the others